# SharePoint Modern Experience - 'Expand Content' cannot be exited

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience

this may seem like an absolutely stupid question, but I genuinely cannot figure it out and it's bordering on insane.

I've accidentally hit this 'Expand content' button (below) in a Modern Experience Library and it's removed the quick links bar, the options bar at the top (the one the button happens to be in) and pretty much everything else. I can't exit it and there's nothing I've been able to find online.

[image: The perpetrator]

[image: Source of immense frustration]

Comment: I have the same issue, and it's driving me nuts. How stupid is it that Microsoft has deployed this into production on our site with no notice or consultation but with such a MAJOR issue that should never had gone out of the first testing phase. It's a new button that's on all of the lists libraries across our tenancy and accidentally hitting it on any of these will break your access to it. FAIL FAIL FAIL FAIL Also it's funny that this post shows up in a "bing" search for the issue, but not in a "google" search. I suspect that the change is merely hours old and that google has not caught up.

Comment: I am also facing the similar issue on my SharePoint site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

that's strange. The command bar should not have disappeared. In fact, it should show a command to collapse the content.

[image]

If you don't see that, you may want to clear cookies, at least those set in the last couple of hours.

Comment: I ended up clearing the cache for the last 24 hours and it resolved it, but I've replicated the issue multiple times across multiple libraries and in both Chrome and IE. Must be a set up issue. I checked the source code and found the collapse content button but it wasn't visible.

Comment: @teylyn Even I faced this issue. No way to come out of Expanded view. May be we can highlight this to Microsoft.

Answer (score 6):

I'm sure this will be "patched out" by Microsoft pretty quickly, but in the meantime you can have users run the following code if they get "stuck" but don't want to clear cache:

1. Press F12 in your browser (if IE, may need to go to '...' -> More Tools -> Developer Tools)
2. Click next to the ">" to focus into the Console and then paste the following:
   `document.querySelectorAll("button[title='Collapse content']")[0].click()`

By way of explanation, like Rogan mentioned, the button is there and works, it's just hidden.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issue and found that the only way to collapse it again is to remove any "?view_parameter_info" off the end of the URL and reload the page.

Not the easiest thing to explain to your end users when you've designed a list that expands well off-screen and requires scrolling to the right. Hope this is patched ASAP.

Comment: That works well. Explain to the users to remove anything after the ".aspx" in the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this in a few tenants, but not all of them I've tested.

In my experience, merely refreshing the page is enough to get the normal view back.

Answer (score 0):

I got a report of this for the first time today. The command bar containing the expanded view control (among other things) would disappear when in expanded view. Thus making it impossible to exit expanded view. However, while testing with the user, a few additional characteristics were discovered:

- **Issue is site *and* user specific:** Issue is being reported by only a handful of users but I cannot reproduce it. None of the impacted users can reproduce the issue on any other site.
- **Issue goes away when disconnecting from a Hub site:** Issue disappeared when the site was disconnected from a Hub site, but came back as soon as it was re-associated.
- **Issue goes away when the browser window size is reduced:** Making the browser window small enough to trigger the responsive UI changes brings the command bar back. Returning it to the original size makes it disappear again. (this is what we are recommending as a workaround until resolved)
- **Issue appears to be browser agnostic:** Got the same results testing from Chrome and Edge Canary. I think those browsers share some Chromium code so maybe that's a thing?